# return from socketIO in C# project

Tags: c#, .net, socket.io

I have this code to receive some data from server. the log inside socket.on give correct data but give 0 at return. And I can not put return into Socket.on.

```
public int GetInfor(string userID)
{
    int result = 0;
    socket.On("data" , (SocketIOEvent e) => {
        formData data= jss.Deserialize<formData>(string.Format("{0}", e.data));
        if (data.err) 
            result = Int32.Parse(data.Infor);
        else result = -1;
        Debug.Log (result);
    });
    Debug.Log (result);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens, because your method returns result which is set to 0 straightaway without waiting for receive any event.

Here's simple solution:

```
public void GetInfor(string userID, Action<int> resultAction)
{
    int result = 0;
    socket.On("data" , (SocketIOEvent e) => {
        formData data= jss.Deserialize<formData>(string.Format("{0}", e.data));
        if (data.err) 
            result = Int32.Parse(data.Infor);
        else 
            result = -1;
        resultAction.Invoke(result); // or just simplt resultAction(result);
    });
}
```

Usage

```
this.GetInfor("exampleUserId", result =>
{
    // do something with result
});
```

Comment: it works great. you helped me so much. thanks. but just one more question.. How can i use the result after and outside of this.getInfor

Comment: Simply assign it's value to local value but again, you have to keep in mind that value is created when event fires.